# react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view is not working for Modal window fields

Tags: react-native

I applied `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` in app.js (which is base file for my app) to make it work throughout the application.

```
return ( 
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView>              
              <AppInitialComponent /> 
              <RouterBar />
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
      );
```

And my application contains several `Modal` windows with fields.

Package is working fine for the fields which are out side of the `Modal` windows , But not working for the fields which are inside the `Modal` windows.

Do I need to call `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` from some where else to make it work for `Modal` window fields as well?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put  in app.js if you have modals. Include it where needed. e.g.

```
   <Modal>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can user KeyboardAwareScrollView package

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
 render(){
return(

  <View>
    <Modal
      animationType={"slide"}
      transparent={false}
      visible={this.props.visible}
      onRequestClose={this.props.closeModal}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        <View style={this.props.styles.descriptionContiner}>
          <View>
            <View style={this.props.styles.descriptionHeading}>
              <Text style = {this.props.styles.descriptionHeadingFont}>{this.props.title}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style = {this.props.styles.CloseModalIcon}>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.closeModal}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/images/delete-sign.png')} 
                  style={this.props.styles.CloseModalImage}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <TextInput
            onChange={(attr, value) => this.props.updateAttr('name', value)}
            value={this.props.value}
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            autoFocus={true}
            multiline={true}
            numberOfLines={8}
            style={styles.input} 
            />
          <View style={this.props.styles.ModalSaveButton}>
          <Button
            title= {this.props.SaveTitle}
            onPress={this.props.closeModal}
            color="#44c8f5"
          />
          </View>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </Modal>
  </View> 
)
```

}
}